# Perl: passing argument to signal handler causes handler to run immediately

Tags: perl, signals

Short version: I'm trying to pass an argument to a signal handler. When I do so, however, the handler runs as soon as the program is launched. Why is this happening, and how can I correct it?

Details: I have the following line in my code: `$SIG{ALRM} = \&timesup($number);`. The signal handler itself is:

```
sub timesup {
    my $num = shift;
    die "Time ran out.\nNumber was: $num\n"
}
```

When I run the program, it immediately runs the signal handler and dies with the specified message. I tested by generating a random value for $number just before the `$SIG{ALRM}` line. The swan song message on dying does print the random value, so I think the argument itself is being passed correctly. But the output is immediate:

```
bassoon:$ ./myscript.pl

Time ran out.
Number was: 4
```

If I take away the argument and simply have `$SIG{ALRM} = \&timesup;`, then the program works as expected. However, in that case I have no way of passing the argument to the subroutine, and have to use a global, which I'd rather not do.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\&timesup($number)` calls the `timesup` sub (`&timesup($number)`) and then takes a reference to the return value (`\`). Calling a sub with `&` should be avoided because this bypasses prototypes and can have certain other effects.

The solution is to wrap your `timesup` application like this:

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub { timesup($number) };
```

This is effectively [*partial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: I see. My understanding was that it was better to assign a reference to the signal hash rather than a sub, because dereferencing is quicker than a function call, so the handler is invoked quicker when the signal is received. But given your explanation of what's going on, I take it that if the handler needs arguments, there isn't a way to use a reference to the subroutine, there has to be a wrapper subroutine? Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @verbose both `\&foo` and `sub { ... }` are code references, which will be dereferenced and called when the signal is triggered. Of course wrapping the actual call inside another sub is less efficient, but that isn't really an issue here – how often will `ALRM` be triggered? Surely less often than once per second.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! I'm grateful for your explanations, as they help me understand what's going on. That's the cool part. The problem fix itself is merely a nice side-effect.

Answer (score -2):

You should set signal handler as follow: `$SIG{ALRM} = 'timesup'`

Comment: This answer is factually wrong (`$SIG{ALRM} = \&handler`) works just fine), and doesn't answer the question why `\&timesup($number)` doesn't produce a code reference.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.